# I'm looking for a javascript logger with indentation and coloring ( it can! be browser specific )

Tags: javascript, logging, colors, stack, indentation

I'm searching for a javascript logger that indents every message based on the stack depth. For example if function A calls function B it should look like:

```
hi from A
    hi from B
```

Also I want it to be able to color the messages if originate from functions from different stacks. That way I can track asynchronous events.

The interface has to be like this:

```
function B(){ log('hi from B'); }
function A(){ log('hi from A'); B(); }
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated : )

Answer (score 2):

I think this function should help you:

```js
var log = function(msg) {
  var $level = 0, parent = arguments.callee.caller;
  while(parent
        && parent.arguments
        && parent.arguments.callee 
        && parent.arguments.callee.caller) {
    parent = parent.arguments.callee.caller;
    $level = $level + 1;
  }
  console.info(Array($level).join("  "), msg);
}
```

Output of the following code is as follows:

```js
function B(){ log('hi from B'); }
function A(){ log('hi from A'); B(); }

B();
A();
```

[image: Output]

The `log` may take a page as a parent callee so you may need to modify output like

```
console.info(Array($level - 1).join("  "), msg);
```

Please note that number of space characters in `join("  ")` specifies how big the indent will be.

I hope that will help.